# How to grant to an openldap user only a specific privilege?

Tags: ubuntu, ldap

I would like to create an user apart from Admin user, who should have access to update password as well as create another user in openldap. I tried configuring the user with the following ldif file. But it is not working as expected, and trows an error *"Unauthorized user while updating password for another user"*:

```
dn: olcDatabase={1}hdb,cn=config
changetype: modify
add: olcAccess
olcAccess: {1}to *
by dn="cn=usrmanager,dc=example,dc=com" write
```

Why is it so? What could be the appropriate configuration?

Comment: Dear reviewers, I suggest a migration to the ServerFault.

Answer (score 0):

You'll first want to look at existing ACLs, as they're processed one after the other. It is not unlikely you would have some prior rule that would only allow passwords edition by self, maybe some read privileges for backups or replication, ... anyway, your rule is probably not evaluated, in regards to user passwords.

As a sidenote, your ACL is probably too large. You would allow your `usrmanager` account re-writing pretty much any attribute, anywhere.

```
olcAccess: {X}to attrs=userPassword by dn="<an-admin-account-dn>" write
    by self write
    by dn="<some-syncrepl-or-backup-account>" read
    by anonymous auth
```